# AWE & SQL Server 2008 Web Edition (32 bit server)

Tags: sql-server

Does SQL Server 2008 Web Edition support AWE?

Answer (score 1):

[Yep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143685.aspx), however AWE is used in an x86 environment.  If you use an x64 environment you won't need it as SQL will automatically have access to all the available memory.

Comment: It is a x86 server. I set 'Lock pages in Memory', enabled AWE and set the 3GB switch (which is a bit different in Windows 2008 as there is no boot.ini) and performance seemed to degrade. Maybe this is because I have exactly 4GB RAM installed and wasn't sure whether to use AWE anyway. What do you think?

Comment: Lock Pages won't do anything on Web Edition.  By default it only works on Enterprise Edition, and it is available via a trace flag for the Standard Edition.  As far as I know it doesn't do anything on the Web or Workgroup editions.  Even if it did, with only 4 Gigs of RAM installed you don't want to stop the OS from managing the memory. How much memory are you allowing SQL to use.  Unless it is over 2 Gigs the 3GB switch and AWE won't do anything for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe so, it is stated that is supports RAM up to the OS max, it would need AWE to access it.

Comment: So why the degredation in performance after AWE was enabled?

Comment: Is the server dedicated to SQL, or running other apps/services as well? What is maximum memory set to in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft will remove AWE support next version of SQL Server.
Because new OS already 64 bit systems and addressing much more RAM sizes